# Flex 4.5.1 check whether file exists in assets folder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm using flex 4.5.1 to build a web application that runs on tomcat server. 
I have a assets folder and in this folder i have some files. I retrieve the name of the files from xml file created from

My problem is that i can not check whether the given filename is in the assets folder. From my search on internet i saw that you can use File class but i dont have that import in flex 4.5.1 and when i add external library of airglobal.swc which contains the filesystem lib, the application freezes itself after running 2 or 3 seconds when i remove the airglobal.swc it works fine.

Are there any ways to check whether file exists in the assets folder?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't use AIR libraries in a web application. How do you access the files that are on your server? HTTP?

Comment: srv.lastResult.person.image is the filepath relative to assets folder and i have image holder personImage. when i want to change the image i do the following "personImage.source = srv.lastResult.person.image" and it reads and shows the image at screen

Comment: Then you have to give an URL, it's HTTP. Right?

Comment: i use http service to get the filename from url and in mxml part at fx:Script  "personImage.source = srv.lastResult.person.image" i do this and it works but given no picture it shows broken link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an URL exists or not:

```
import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLoader();
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://url of your file"));

private function onStatus(e:HTTPStatusEvent):void
{
    trace(e.status);
}

private function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace( e.text);
}
```